# Different Cameras render different Objects or Collections

Tags: modeling, camera

I have looked around online for anything on this topic but have been unfruitful. I have a project where I am rendering a few different floor plans. Each floor plan varies in size and I don't want to have to adjust the camera for every unit (Talking like 26 different units).  Is there a way to have one camera didcated to only geometry located in a specific collection? That way, each unit has its own camera associated with it and I can keep each of the units centered in the camera.

Because there is a lot of units I don't want to have a separate file for each one having to adjust all of the settings and materails manually for each one. Any thoughts?

Comment: i think you should explain a bit more what you really want to achieve. If you don't place the camera manually, how should the cam know from which position it should record?

Comment: My idea, is to have 26 different cameras for each unit. To make it simple, I will use a 1 bedroom unit (1B) and a 2 bedroom unit (2B) as an example. I will have one camera deidcated for 1B and another for 2B. When I render out the 1B unit, I don't want the 2B unit to show up in the render as well. Is there a way to assign objects, prefereably in a collection, to one camera, so when I go to batch print all of the units, each one will be separate? Maybe its not possible for the cameras to do that. It might just be better if I move each units on the X-axis enough to avoid each other.

Comment: did you ever try different view layer? that's perfect for that, if i understood you right